# No DocBrokers are configured

Tags: c#, content-management-system, documentum

I get this error while trying to access documentum through webtop. "An error has occurred.

[DM_DOCBROKER_E_NO_DOCBROKERS]error: "No DocBrokers are configured".   Iam trying to access documentum for the first time.

Any help ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

check the dfc.properties file, assuming D65, the file is in [webtop base]/Web-Inf/classes.

In that file, edit this line to point to the correct content server where the docbroker is.  either ip address or host name should work.

```
dfc.docbroker.host[0]=[docbroker host]
```

Answer (score 0):

First guess on a new setup... Is your docbroker started?

Second guess, your dfc.properties is incorrect or not updated at all. Can you add it to the question?

Comment: Yes Michael..I checked the services console...It says Doc Broker services started.. Any other suggestion ?